# Preventing API calls from uwanted internal services/journeys

Tags: rest, spring-security, mule-esb

On web applications, how do you prevent APIs/microservices on a multilayered application are protected to ensure that are no unwanted calls coming from a journey that is not intended to? (internally)

Assuming a web-login API/webservice consuming a shared LOGIN service(backed by the IAM DB) will generate a JWT token. On a normal journey the end user would start a purchase (e.g. buy credits), which triggers a more generic purchasing service (e.g. credits). Due to the nature of the business, Login and weblogin are tightly coupled, same as bui-credits and credits, however the WEB-LOGIN service should not be allowed to call the CREDITS service.

An option we thought about is that all services on the second layer(login and credits) should implement a client-id/secret with the authorized caller. 
In the example this would prevent that CREDITS to be called from Web-Login(red arrow) which is not a valid scenario, as web-login is unable to hijack 'buy-credits' credentials

[Cross API Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jejiw.png)

Any thoughts are welcome as I wasn't able to find a pattern for API security within the same border/application. I'm aware of B2B pattern but not sure how(or if) it's applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some kind of authorization between the layers seems sensible.

If you use API Manager, you could use one of the standard policies, like [client id enforcement](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/client-id-based-policies) or JWT validation policies, that can be applied above your existing APIs without modifying them.